# Issue in UI layout for application that opens through automation

Tags: user-interface, cucumber-jvm

I am trying to perform some operation on a webpage.
My framework is built using Cucumber , Java
If I open the application manually , then the fields on the page are displaying with proper layout.
But if I open the same page through automation (chrome driver instance same as manual) , then the lay out is not proper due to which I am not able to proceed further. 
I checked proxy and firewall configuration also which is fine.
Not sure why through automation UI is not proper.

Note: I also added a wait command for around 2 minutes to make the page load completely . SO its not an issue of page loading.
The same code works with my another colleague's system with same OS.

Can anyone give some hint on it what could be the issue?

Comment: Are you using Selenium, ChromeDriver? Which versions? (Are you using the same version of ChromeDriver as your coworkers?)

Comment: Yes I am using selenium chrome driver and yes me and my colleague use the same framework where we have stored the drivers. So yes, we are using same version of ChromeDriver

Comment: Please post your ChromeOptions (e.g. arguments, preferences and capabilities) that you pass to class ChromeDriver when creating your WebDriver instance. For example, did you specify "start-maximized" ?

Comment: Are there any other differences between your machines? (OS etc)